# Is there any reason why new data is not rendering

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following JQuery Code:

```
 $.ajax({
                            url: "/Configuration/TestPlan/GetTestPlanDdlList",
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            // async :false,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                //call pageloader 
                                showImageLoader();
                            },
                            data:jsonString,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                data = data.allDDlList;
                                $(".ajaxmask, #imgAjaxLoading").remove();
```

ASP.net controller:

```
[HttpPost]
var result = Json(new { allDDlList = allDDlList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            result.MaxJsonLength = Constants.MaxJsonLength;
            return result;
```

I have a few cases with a few users where they are not seeing the latest data. When i have them clear out their browser cache and do a hard refresh, it then works fine.

Any suggestion for what could be still being cached here and any suggestion for a solution to make sure people don't get old data?

Comment: Try adding `cache: false` to the AJAX request properties

Comment: Hey @Rory i tried that too, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's ajax request will cache the results. To handle cache in our application set headers to no-cache.

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
});
```

Comment: The headers are already passed through backend as well as set through the meta tags. And this is also similar to cache: false

Comment: What i have now done is setting the max-age to 0 in the headers, so that the request will be fetched as a new request each time.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some more testing and i would like to add here what i have done. So far i am getting positive results. But cant assume what the user would perform next. So here are my findings.

I have set the cache to false in ajax property. Then i added a query string to the URL. 
I have set max-age to 0 in request headers so that the request will be fetched as a new request each time on the click event.

Below is the JQuery Code :

```
 var data = {'areaMappingList' :  areaDataSource, 'IsParent': viewBagIsParent};

                        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
                        debugger
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Configuration/URL/URL?IsParent="+ viewBagIsParent +"",
                            type: 'POST',
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            // async :false,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                //call pageloader 
                                showImageLoader();
                            },
                            data:jsonString,
                            headers: {
                                'Cache-Control':'max-age=0, public'
                            },
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) { }
```